# Hyper-V Ubuntu Networking Problems Copying Large Amounts of Data

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v

I am trying to copy a large amount (about 50 GB) of data over my network from a Hyper-V-hosted virtual machine running Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal) to another (non-virtual) Ubuntu host that I plan to use for testing upgrades to one of our web applications.  The problem I am having is with the virtual machine, which I shall refer to in what follows as "source.host".  This machine is running 64-bit Ubuntu Server with the 2.6.38-8-server kernel and the Microsoft Linux Integration Components for Hyper-V kernel modules (hv_utils, hv_timesource, hv_netvsc, hv_blkvsc, hv_storvsc, and hv_vmbus) loaded.  It uses a Hyper-V "synthetic network adapter" for its networking interface.

To do the copy, I log on to the machine with the data and run the following commands (Call the remote machine "destination.host".):

```
$ cd /path/to/data
$ tar -cvf - datafolder/ | ssh user@destination.host "cat > ~/data.tar"
```

This runs for a while and then suddenly stops after transferring somewhere from 2-6 GB.  The terminal on the source.host machine displays a `Write failed:  broken pipe` error.  The odd part is this:  after this occurs, the "source.host" machine is no longer able to talk to the rest of the network.  I cannot ping any other hosts on the network from the "source.host" machine, and I cannot ping the "source.host" machine from any other host on the network.  I am equally unable to access the any of the web services hosted on "source.host".

Running `ifconfig` on "source.host" shows the network adapter to be up and running as usual with the correct IP address and everything.  I tried restarting the networking service with

```
$ /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

but the problem does not go away.  Restarting the machine makes it capable of talking to the network again -- it can ping and be pinged by other hosts, and the web services are also accessible and usable as normal -- but attempting the copy operation again results in the same failure, requiring another restart.

As an experiment, I tried replacing the `tar` -- `ssh` pipeline above with a straight `scp`:

```
$ scp -r datafolder/ user@destination.host:~
```

but to no avail

Thinking that the issue might have to do with the kernel packet-send buffers filling up, I tried increasing the buffer size to 12 MB (up from the 128 KB default) with

```
# echo 12582911 > /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max
```

but this also had no effect.

I'm guessing at this point that it might be a problem with the Microsoft synthetic network driver, but I don't really know.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What kind of NIC do you have in the Hyper-V host server (these problems seem to be very common with cheap NICs like Realtek or Via)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The host server NIC is a Broadcom card.

Comment: Has the firmware been updated this year? In Dec 2011 Broadcom released new firmware for most of their server NICs that fixed quite a few problems.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling broadcom teaming if enabled on the hyper-v network connection?

We have had to set ours to Active/Passive as the broadcom drivers + linux vm were causing mac address confusion and eventually causing the Linux guest to lose all network connectivity until rebooted/live migrated or virtual networks re-connected.

Answer (score 0):

Yoû're quite right with the hv_netvsc module. Some notable changes to this driver (including hv_vmbus) only whent into 2.6.39 and 3.0 where they are much more stable. Regular network stall or random crashes were quite normal on any Ubuntu and Debian VM I saw using these

Up till 2.6.38 at least, I saw random network loss quite regularly, after that it's much more stable - but still not perfect.